# Trying to generate assembly code from C

Tags: c, assembly

I have created an assembly code from a C project, but when i run it I get this compilation error:

```
Compilation Error
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; 
defaulting to 00000000004000b0
/tmp/tmpM7HOI5/squares.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `malloc'
main.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `perror'
main.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `exit'
main.c:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `stdin'
main.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `fgets'
main.c:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `atoi'
main.c:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `free'
main.c:(.text+0x14d): undefined reference to `malloc'
main.c:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `stdin'
main.c:(.text+0x16c): undefined reference to `fgets'
main.c:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `strtok'
main.c:(.text+0x18f): undefined reference to `atoi'
main.c:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to `strtok'
main.c:(.text+0x1c5): undefined reference to `atoi'
main.c:(.text+0x1ef): undefined reference to `strtok'
main.c:(.text+0x1ff): undefined reference to `atoi'
main.c:(.text+0x229): undefined reference to `strtok'
main.c:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to `atoi'
main.c:(.text+0x25e): undefined reference to `free'
main.c:(.text+0x2f6): undefined reference to `printf'
```

It seems that all library calls become undefined.

To compile I used:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -O2 -lm -S main.c
```

Comment: Those errors are because you don't link with the standard C library.

Comment: Also note that you don't get compilation errors. Or assembly errors. You get *linker* errors.

Comment: Is the compilation step shown the command that prints the errors? Or is there another command you haven't shown?

Comment: it does seem that the command shown is not the one that produced the errors.

Comment: just compile how you normally would and add -save-temps (instead of -S)

Comment: may still need to deal with the linking, but you are asking two separate questions here, please ask one.

Comment: The command shown is the one I used to generate the assembly code. That went fine without warnings. I can also compile and run it without "-S" and it runs fine. The problem is that the assembly code will not compile and run.

Comment: Why do you show the command that works fine rather than the one that fails?

Comment: @prl because I was wondering if it was correct considering that the output i get (assembly code) does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your GCC command only generates assembly code, but your error list is for a linker invocation.

I suspect the `-lm` option is causing the compiler driver to invoke the linker - it is not necessary to specify a library if you are generating only assembly for a single translation unit.

The linker is complaining about the lack of the C standard library and crt0.0 C runtime-start-up.

Remove the unnecessary `-lm` option - you are not intending to link, so teh library is irrelevant.

Comment: I tried, but I still get the same Compilation error when I try to run the generated assembly code.

Comment: @user2081417 Please show us the command line you use to “run the generated assembly code.”

Comment: The code is uploaded to a remote server running: Assembly (x64) by (binutils 2.25). So I am not running any commands. Also the expected format is AT&T, but gcc does that by standard

Comment: @user2081417 : You cannot 'run' assembly code.  You have to _assemble_ it, then link it.  If you are doing that then you are not providing complete information in your question.

Comment: @user2081417 : That is exactly the information you need to add to the question. We are left guessing due to incomplete information.  The command you posted is not what is issuing the errors shown.  The compiler translates a single compilation unit - you are not linking.  The remote server is attempting to link the code, but it has not been provided the standard library or start-up code.  Simple as that.  If you are using unusual development procedures such as this, you do need to mention that.

Answer (score -1):

Your `-lm` links to the math library.  Similarly, you need `-lc` to link to the C library.

Comment: I tried, but I still get the same Compilation error when I try to run the generated assembly code.